# How do I fix this Exception when starting spark-job-server?

Tags: linux, scala, apache-spark, sbt, spark-jobserver

I am trying to start the [spark-job-server](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver) on my linux machine. I did the following:

1. Installed the cloudera distriution CDH(5.x) and gotten it up and running
2. Downloaded `spark-job-server` from the above mentioned github
3. Extracted the project into some folder
4. Installed sbt-0.13.8 and set path variable and able to run the sbt command
5. Went to the project directory (`spark-job-server/`) and ran the sbt command
6. From SBT shell, I have typed "re-start", which is suppposed to start the `spark-job-server`.

Then, I got this Exception:

```
  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-mapreduce-client-app;2.2.0: not found
[warn]  :: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-yarn-api;2.2.0: not found
[warn]  :: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-mapreduce-client-core;2.2.0: not found
[warn]  :: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient;2.2.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]          org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-app:2.2.0
[warn]            +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:2.2.0
[warn]            +- org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.10:1.3.1 (/home/analytics/data_dir/spark-jobserver-master/project/Build.scala#L186)
[warn]            +- spark.jobserver:job-server-api_2.10:0.5.2-SNAPSHOT
[warn]          org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-api:2.2.0
[warn]            +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:2.2.0
[warn]            +- org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.10:1.3.1 (/home/analytics/data_dir/spark-jobserver-master/project/Build.scala#L186)
[warn]            +- spark.jobserver:job-server-api_2.10:0.5.2-SNAPSHOT
[warn]          org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-core:2.2.0
[warn]            +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:2.2.0
[warn]            +- org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.10:1.3.1 (/home/analytics/data_dir/spark-jobserver-master/project/Build.scala#L186)
[warn]            +- spark.jobserver:job-server-api_2.10:0.5.2-SNAPSHOT
[warn]          org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient:2.2.0
[warn]            +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:2.2.0
[warn]            +- org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.10:1.3.1 (/home/analytics/data_dir/spark-jobserver-master/project/Build.scala#L186)
[warn]            +- spark.jobserver:job-server-api_2.10:0.5.2-SNAPSHOT
[warn] Credentials file /root/.bintray/.credentials does not exist
[warn] Credentials file /root/.bintray/.credentials does not exist
[warn] Credentials file /root/.bintray/.credentials does not exist
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last job-server-api/*:update for the full output.
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last akka-app/*:update for the full output.
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last job-server-api/*:update for the full output.
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last akka-app/*:update for the full output.
[error] (job-server-api/*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-mapreduce-client-app;2.2.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-yarn-api;2.2.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-mapreduce-client-core;2.2.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient;2.2.0: not found
[error] (akka-app/*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-mapreduce-client-app;2.2.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-yarn-api;2.2.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-mapreduce-client-core;2.2.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient;2.2.0: not found
[error] (job-server-api/*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-mapreduce-client-app;2.2.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-yarn-api;2.2.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-mapreduce-client-core;2.2.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient;2.2.0: not found
[error] (akka-app/*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-mapreduce-client-app;2.2.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-yarn-api;2.2.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-mapreduce-client-core;2.2.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient;2.2.0: not found
[error] Total time: 5 s, completed Aug 6, 2015 1:29:26 PM
```

Some more information:

- I have manually downloaded these dependencies and placed them
- when I rerun restart command again still sbt is not able to find the same dependency which i have copied in `.ivy2` folder

How can I fix this?

Comment: To help other people to help you, it is necessary that you post a minimal, correct, verifiable, example that others can reproduce that demonstrates the problem.  You can click the "edit" link below your question to add the necessary details.

Comment: You are getting the exception when you run *what*, exactly? No one knows, from what is written, which of the steps on the github page is causing that problem. We also don't know which steps you have completed.

Comment: This is the step "Development mode" in the Git hub page which I mentioned in question.  When I run reStart command from sbt shell i am getting this error.

Comment: looks like you can only fetch these JAR files if you have proper credentials for the repo. do you have these credentials?

Comment: I was able to resolve most of the dependency, but not this. Yes I have a  proper credentials.

Comment: I have downloaded these dependency separately and placed it inside  .ivy2 folder. that not resolving my problem

Comment: One more thing we have used to HTTP proxy here to download dependency